# How to pass parameter to jsp page

Tags: jsp, view

I have a form like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div>
            <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>
            <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="upload" />
            </form>          
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

with a backing class, which read an uploaded .csv file:

```
public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet 
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        //process only if its multipart content
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            try 
            {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                         new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem item : multiparts)
                {
                    if(!item.isFormField())
                    {
                        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(item.getName(), null);
                        List<String[]> valueStrings = readCSVFile(tempFile);
                        //the line I am having trouble with
                    }
                }

               //File uploaded successfully
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                //TODO: handle exception
            }          

        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("message",
                                 "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

I want to pass the array `values` to another view, which looks something like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <%
        for(String[] line : values)
        {
            for(String value : line)
            {
                System.out.print(value+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("<br/>");
        }
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You are already using same functionality to pass data from Servlet to JSP. As you are passing `message` from Servlet to forwarded `error.jsp` using `setAttribute()`. just do in the same way and get the value back using `getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have 3 solutions:**

**1. Use Forward:**

//the line I am having trouble with

request.setAttribute ( "values", valueStrings );

request.getRequestDispatcher( "/path_to_jsp.jsp" ).forward ( request, response)

**2. Use HTTPSession if Redirect**

- Cache valueStrings in HttpSession and perform Redirect to jsp file

**3. Include valueStrings as Query parameter**

- For this solution. You need to convert valueStrings to String and include this String as query parameter. In other jsp file, you need to convert String back to valueStrings.

Comment: which one would you recommend?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. You want perform Forward, you use solution 1. Else use solution 2,3 if Redirect is required. I think for your case, use Solution 1.